# module 'h5py' has no attribute 'File'

Tags: tensorflow, pip, h5py

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
base_model = VGG16(input_shape = (224, 224, 3),include_top = False, weights = 'imagenet')
```

It is not working even after uninstalling and installing pip install h5py several times :(

Comment: adding the tensorflow and h5py version could be useful here.. (I remember I had a similar problem, because h5py version was too new, so I would try an earlier release of h5py)

Comment: make sure none of your files are called `h5py.py`

Comment: make sure none of your files are called `h5py.py`

Comment: How to make sure that? and can u share which version worked exactly for u @lhlmgr?

Comment: This could be due to installation of packages from different sources like pip and conda, try uninstalling it in both and do a fresh installation, if this dosen't work then create a new virtual environment and install packages using only single source, i.e either pip or conda and try running the code. This should work.